# Can I control the page based on content in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox to "pop up" user profile when someone clicks on the profile link. The profile is loaded in iframe, because I would like them to be able to click couple of links inside and keep it in same popup. The problem occurs when user's session has timed out, because if the popup is opened it shows login page within the popup.

I'm wondering what I can do to control "outer" page based on what is returned in colorbox iframe. I'd like to redirect the entire page to login page not just the content of colorbox iframe. Is there a way to do this with javascript?

Please let me know if I did not describe the problem well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste this inside the <header> of your login page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window!=window.top) { window.top.location.href = window.location.href; }
</script>
```

This way you can show any page inside an iframe, except for the login page, wich will replace the entire page.

The script detects if the page is being loaded in the main window or inside an iframe, then perform a redirection to "escape" from the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the following statement to redirect opening page.

```
window.opener.document.location.href= "/login";
```

If you are using ajax to load the content of iframe, than you can easily use this statement on the basis of ajax response. If you are not using ajax, than you have to send following response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.document.location.href= "/login";
</script>
```